# How do we evaluate this integral containing log

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, logarithms

> If $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+(\ln x)(\ln x) \ldots \infty} \forall x \in[1,
> > \infty)$ then $\int_1^{2 e} f(x) d x$ equals is :

I have no idea on how to approach this type of integral. The only step I could write properly was:

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+(\ln x)(\ln x) \ldots \infty} \Rightarrow f(x)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{1+(\ln x)^n}$

I tried thinking about where the graphs of log would give positive and how the powers of exponents would effect the limits. But I just can't get a knack on how to apply it here.
Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 x&\text{if}\, 1\leq x < e\\
0 &\text{if}\, e < x
\end{cases}$

Comment: @user3257842 ok, so how does that help?

Comment: Do piecewise integration

Comment: @johnyb ok I did understand that...But what I didnt understand is that how that piecewise function defined works

Comment: Is this even defined? I mean the integration.

Comment: @user3257842 what if $x=e$ ...then will you say that $f(x)=x/2$?

Comment: What does "$1+\ln(x)\ln(x)\ldots\infty$" mean?

Comment: @Accelerator The OP means the product of the $\ln(x)$'s to infinity. I think you are trying to be technical, am I right? :)

Comment: @KamalSaleh If it is, then it's a strange way to show we are multiplying infinitely many natural logs because it seems like an abuse of the notation $\infty$.

Comment: @Accelerator yes, that is true. But the OP realized this and made it a limit so that it won't seem as if $\infty$ is a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x=1$ the $\ln x$ in the denominator is zero. At $x=e$ the function is $\frac e2$. When $x>e$ we just get $0$. When $1<x<e$ we have that $f(x)=x$. So the answer is $$\int_1^exdx=\frac{e^2-1}2$$We can numerically verify this answer on desmos by making $n$ bigger. This integral slowly converges by the way.

Comment: I'm too surprised to speak...that a 14 year old knows this much calculus

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad It's not hard. Take a look at the link: https://www.theatlantic.com/education/archive/2014/03/5-year-olds-can-learn-calculus/284124/

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Rewrite the integral as $$\int_1^{e}f(x)dx+\int_e^{2e}f(x)dx$$

Comment: It's a really great idea to split the integral into two. I really like this hint. +1

Comment: @KamalSaleh (and the OP): it is nothing more than the very first comments above,  by user3257842 and johnnyb. Come on, Elizabeth...

Comment: @AnneBauval True. Sometimes my brain doesn't work...I think this happens when you are just only 13 years old and weird enough to learn calculus

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman I'm 14. Stop complaining :) By the way, the question is closed since it doesn't say where the problem is.